# disable text selection in gwt

Tags: user-interface, gwt, select

i am pretty new to GWT,
i have an image that i have placed a text on top, i need the text to look as part of the image. 
i have used the image widget and the HTML widget to position it on top of it, i need this text to change according the locale.

the problem that the text is selectable, so it does not look right. 
1) is there any way to make the text un-selectable?
2) is there a better way to achieve that?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is handled by the `user-select` attribute.

See: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1184318&page=1